# How to repeat code using __VA_ARGS__ in c++?

Tags: c++, macros, header-files

I want to create a macro in C++ that does the following.

```cpp
#define SETUP_BULK(...) \
SETUP_HELPER(__VA_ARG__) \ // repeat this for all __VA_ARGS__
```

Is this possible? I looked up other questions on iterating `__VA_ARGS__` but to no avail.

I can't use anything other than macros, or that would defeat the purpose of my goal - to dynamically setup structures with my custom JSON parser.

Eg:

```cpp
SETUP_BULK(Struct_A, Struct_B, Struct_C)
```

would turn into

```
SETUP_HELPER(Struct_A);
SETUP_HELPER(Struct_B);
SETUP_HELPER(Struct_C);
```

Comment: If you have C++17 you can use fold expressions

Comment: Can you use fold expressions in macros?

Comment: If you're using fold expressions, then you don't *need* macros. `SETUP_BULK` can just be a regular method

Comment: Example: https://godbolt.org/z/jvb5oa913

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on doing this at the level of macros, the simplest solution is to use [Boost.Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>

// ...

#define SETUP_HELPER2(r, data, elem) SETUP_HELPER(elem)

#define SETUP_BULK(...) \
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(SETUP_HELPER2, _, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/osnTzqK5a)